# Extension for navigation to file by string in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, navigation, resharper

I need a key shortcut (Visual Studio 2013) to open file which name corresponds to string in editor in which caret currently resides. For example:

I'm in JavaScript file:

```
[...]
$mdDialog.show({
    controller: 'someC|ontroller',
    templateUrl: '/SomeTemplateUrl/'
});
[...]
```

My caret's position is in 'someController' (marked as '|'). I want to have a shortcut that will take the string 'someController', process it to UpperCamelCase and find file with that name in my solution.

Another example:

I'm in .cshtml file:

```
<some-di|rective></some-directive>
```

My caret is again marked as '|'. I want to have shortcut to get string 'some-directive', process it to SomeDirective and find file with that name.

I presume I need to write some kind of extension for VS or ReSharper for such thing (parsing part of text in editor according to some regexp, process this string and open file).

Is this possible?

I know I could copy string, press Ctrl+t and paste it, make it CamelCase and remove '-' from it, but this takes time. I need shortcut for it to be quick.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not exactly what you're looking for, but try Ctrl + , (control comma). This brings up the Quick Navigation box.

If you type in lowercase, it will perform a fuzzy string match. When using uppercase characters it will do an exact search.

It allows you to search for file names, types, method names and other members. Use the up/down arrow keys to navigate the results, press enter to go to the selected result.